# Cant plot what i want

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to make a plot with checkbuttons, but something isnt working, can anyone help me with it?
This is the code that i have

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons


data=pd.read_csv('top10MX.csv')
data=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
data.set_index('Torneo',inplace=True)
data


[enter image description here][1]
This image is the data,is an 8x10 matrix



x=range(2014,2021,1)
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]

y1=data["Atlas"].values
y2=data["Club America"].values
y3=data["Cruz Azul"].values
y4=data["Guadalajara"].values
y5=data["Leon"].values
y6=data["Monterrey"].values
y7=data["Necaxa"].values
y8=data["Pumas"].values
y9=data["Tigres UANL"].values
y10=data["Toluca"].values

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
p1,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="lightcoral",label="Atlas",visible=True)
p2,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="yellow",label="Club America",visible=True)
p3,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="blue",label="Cruz Azul",visible=False)
p4,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="red",label="Guadalajara",visible=False)
p5,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="forestgreen",label="Leon",visible=False)
p6,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="dodgerblue",label="Monterrey",visible=False)
p7,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="orangered",label="Necaxa",visible=False)
p8,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="gold",label="Pumas",visible=False)
p9,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="darkorange",label="Tigres UANL",visible=False)
p10,=ax.plot(x,y1,color="tomato",label="Toluca",visible=False)
lines=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10]

plt.axis([2014,2020,1,18])
plt.ylabel("Posicion final en el torneo",fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel("Torneo",fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+2, 2))
plt.title('Top 10 most popular MX teams in torneos clausura 2014-2020',fontsize=18)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.001,1),ncol=1,fontsize=12)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

labels=["Atlas","Club America","Cruz Azul","Guadalajara","Leon","Monterrey","Necaxa","Pumas","Tigres UANL","Toluca"]
activated=[True,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
axCheckButton=plt.axes([1.13,0.47,0.3,0.4])
chxbox=CheckButtons(axCheckButton,labels,activated)

def set_visible(label):
    index=labels.index(label)
    lines[index].set_visible(not lines[index].get_visible())
    plt.draw()

chxbox.on_clicked(set_visible)

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdDM9.png)
This is what I get, In theory it should plot the data of the first 2 columns, instead it only plot the data of the first column, and the checkbuttons dont work

any tips or suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I already figured it out. LOL